# relative z-index'ing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, z-index

I'm trying to design a map using images that overlap in an isometric format.
Right now, i have 2 different designs, each one fixes the other's issue. Here is the current setup:
http://mc1.empirebattles.com/map/maplayout.html

The display on the left has issues with the vertical overlap, and the display on the right has issues with the horizontal overlap.

I know that the reason is due to the fact that when a z-index is applied to the parent container, the subsequent z-indexes applied to the children is localized inside the parent.... but i still need the 'row' effect to span across the multiple parent divs.

I know one solution is to just not assign a z-index to the parent divs, and just assign ascending/descending z-indexes to each row, but in the final product, the parent divs will be created dynamically, and I'm trying to avoid having to do calculations at each row for relative z-index....

I cant think of any other way to do it though... anyone else have any ideas on *how to apply z-index relatively?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never found a way to interweave z-indexes for things in different relative or absolute containers.

I think of it like two books. In real life, you could kind of half-open both books and wedge them together so some of the pages are in between each other, like this:
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_e3GqvYXugb8/Se11YQaT-YI/AAAAAAAAAGQ/ljKewd_WMj0/s320/PhoneBook.jpg

In CSS, this isn't possible.

I think the most straightforward thing is to decide on an absolute frame, like the screen size, or the whole map, and position and z-index all objects against that single parent. Then you can treat all game objects like... well like independent objects and not worry about these odd row containers and other layout specific elements.

Comment: Well, in my old map, it was static, with each object globally positioned relative to the map container. However, I'm upgrading the design to a dynamic map, so that I could create new cells above, below, and to the sides of the current 'map'.... which is where the weaving comes in.
Right now, the only way I can think to do it, is on the creation of the object, find out the y coordinate range of that cell, and take the opposite, and make it the z-index for the row. (so if the y coord is -50, the z-index is 50, etc etc).
I was avoiding that, due to post-process application of the z-index

Comment: After a bunch of other research, and looking at all the different ways to do it, i decided to just do global positions, which ended up like this: http://mc1.empirebattles.com/map/jquery_map.html

Comment: Cool man. Looks awesome. I think it'll keep your object structure simpler (as in, the objects on the map will have to keep track of less or no optimization related junk like what dynamic map zone they're in).

Answer (score 0):

A way to avoid *calculations* is to reserve ranges ahead of time for each row. Let's say you can have a max number of 100 units in each row then elements in each row will get an offset of `100*n` where `n` is the row number.

Is that workable for you?

Comment: well, the idea right now is to have each 'cell, have 5 in each row, and have 10 rows per cell (so that dynamic loading is separated into chunks, instead of 1 giant load)